# Trying to scrape a table via Watir and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm new to ruby and I am trying to scrape a table and put it onto a csv. I want to scrape the table from this url: http://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2015/

I need to record all the info in the table, which would be td class="c1" through td class="c8". My while loop is not working properly so I haven't been able to automate.

I'll post the code I currently have, but it is basically nothing.

```
require 'watir'
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto 'http://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2015/'
acount = 49
p = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(b.html)
company = p.css(css).text
company = []
puts css
#right > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.c2
"#right > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td"
csscompany1 = ".cd2"
csscompany1 = ".cd"
css1 = "#right > table > tbody > tr:nth-child"
css2 = "(#count)"
css3 = " > td.c2"
while count != 49 do
acss = "#{css1}#{css2}#{css3}
company.push(p.css(acss).text)
count += 1
end
```

Comment: It would help if you could breakdown the problem into a single question. As it reads now, it sounds like there are 3 components - scraping data from the original table, navigating to sub-pages and scraping data from the sub-pages. However, the question is not clear which one you are stuck on, what exactly you want and where the problem is. Providing a more specific question would make it easier to get a useful answer.

Comment: Hey Justin! I'll try and simplify the problem then; right now, all I want to do is scrape data from the original table.

Comment: I looked at the web site. They have changed it now data you are trying to scrape is no longer stored in a table but they have used `div` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are over-specifying the CSS-selectors:

- You want the `td` elements with class `c1` to `c8`, but that is really all cells in the row.
- The script is iterating over 50 rows of the table, but the table actually has more rows than that. There are blank rows every 10 rows.

The script can be greatly simplified by:

- Noticing that the rows you care about have a class of `data_row`. This will handle the ignoring of the blank rows.
- Using Ruby's built-in enumerable methods, which iterate over collections without needing to worry about indices.

Applying these principles:

```
require 'watir'
require 'nokogiri'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto 'http://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2015/'
p = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(b.html)

# Get the relevant rows
data_rows = p.css('tr.data_row')

# Iterate over each row
data = data_rows.map { |data_row|
  # For each row, collect the text of each td element
  data_row.css('td').map(&:text)
}

# data will be 2D matrix of the table
data
#=> [
#=>    ["1", "Ultra Mobile", "100,849%", "$118.2m", "Telecommunications", "California", "Los Angeles", "105"],
#=>    ["2", "TRYFACTA", "28,365%", "$34.4m", "IT Services", "California", "San Francisco", "221"],
#=>    etc.
#=> ]
```